# Jquery change background-image from a button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to chance background image of a divison from a button without using function.

```
<input onclick="jQuery('#Div1').hide();jQuery('#Div2').show(); jQuery('#main').css("background-image", "url('../../Content/images/clear.png')");" type="button" class="t-button" style="width: 250px" value="Text" /><br />
```

Hide and show works well, but when I added change the background image it did not work.  I have several buttons on the same page, and would like to change images accord to each button.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Is your image URL correct?  Does the div already have background CSS to provide the positioning info?

Comment: Yes the div has background image, and the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Css and javascript its possible with simple way.Use and try below code ...does it help ?

```
$(function){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed');
        }
    });
}
```

CSS

```
.expanded {background: url(img/x.gif) no-repeat left top;}
.collapsed {background: url(img/y.gif) no-repeat left top;}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish, this works well if I have one or two buttons, the challenge is I have more than 30 buttons on the same page!